# docker login fails when done in .bashrc

Tags: ubuntu, bash, docker, amazon-web-services, bashrc

At the end of my .bashrc file I have the following:

```
docker login -u AWS -p $(aws --region us-east-2 ecr get-login-password) 636602586062.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

However, whenever I open up a new shell I get this error:

```
INFO[0000] Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint  error="login attempt to https://636602586062.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 403 Forbidden"
login attempt to https://636602586062.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 403 Forbidden
```

The command works fine if I manually run it after the prompt but it doesn't work in the .bashrc file.

The credentials were set by doing `aws configure`. The `aws` CLI tool, in turn, was installed by me doing the following:

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Any ideas as to why it's not working and what I can do to fix it?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: This lacks info. How do you set your AWS credentials? I'd guess they're in some env which is set after that line is called.

Comment: @Destroy666 - the credentials were set with `aws configure`, which I installed by doing `curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"; unzip awscliv2.zip; sudo ./aws/install`. So it's not like I'm using some custom method to set them..

Comment: Does it works with : `aws --region us-east-2 ecr get-login-password | docker login 636602586062.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -u AWS --password-stdin` ?

Comment: (1) Is the command at the *very* end of your `.bashrc`? If not, what is there after the command? (2) From `.bashrc`, do you run anything asynchronously? What is it? (3) Not quoting `$()` in Bash is almost always wrong. I'm not saying this is the culprit here; I'm saying get used to double-quoting because otherwise [it will bite you sooner or later](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618).

Comment: if `--password-stdin` does not work, try adding `aws --region us-east-2 ecr get-login-password` by itself to the end of your `.bashrc` to make sure it has output and isn't erroring when run during logon

Comment: @hidigoudi - that seems to work! If you post it as the answer I'll award you the bounty - thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you use is not recommended by the documentation, the option `-p` to provide the password is not secure.

> To run the docker login command non-interactively, you can set the
> --password-stdin flag to provide a password through STDIN. Using STDIN prevents the password from ending up in the shell's history, or
> log-files.

[Reference here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#password-stdin)

The command should be :

```
aws --region us-east-2 ecr get-login-password | docker login 636602586062.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -u AWS --password-stdin
```

**OR**

```
aws --region us-east-2 ecr get-login-password | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin 636602586062.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

Those above commands do not use interactive shell.

I admit I don't know exactly why your command doesn't work in the `.bashrc` file, it's in any case related to the `aws` command which doesn't produce output in a `subshell` from the `.bashrc` (because you open a subshell with `$(...)`).

Hope this answer helps you.